# Remove nth element from array (char *)

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any C function that remove **N**-th element from char* (considering char* as array)?

Example:

`char* tab       -->    |5|4|5|1|8|3|`

`remove_elt(tab, 3)    -->    5|4|5|8|3|`

Comment: No, but it's very simple to write one.

Comment: I know that it is very simple, but I've asked about existing function. If not, I will accept answer with implementation.

Comment: Well, if you know where the end of the array is, then yes technically there is: `memmove`.  I take it we're talking about an array where you know the size, rather than a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question as posed is a little unclear.  You suggest it's not a string, but you don't specify the array size in your imaginary function call.  That would lead to the current answer which treats the data as a null-terminated string.

An improved version of that answer would recognise that you don't need to call `strlen`:

```
void remove_elt(char *str, int i)
{
    for(; str[i]; i++) str[i] = str[i+1];
}
```

But if it's an array where you store the size (rather than using `0` as an end-marker), then you would need to supply that size to your function.  In that case, you could use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) which can copy overlapping memory:

```
void remove_elt( char *str, int elem, int *size )
{
    if( elem < --*size ) {
        memmove( &str[elem], &str[elem + 1], *size - elem );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make one:

```
void remove_elt(char *str, int i) {
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (; i < len - 1 ; i++)
    {
       str[i] = str[i+1];
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
}
```